# "python" points to Python 2.7 under macOS Homebrew

Tags: macos, python, homebrew, django

[image: Unable to run python 3.7.2]

I'm trying to setup and run server through Django, but I can't seem to make Python 3.7.2 replace Python 2.7.14.

Comment: What does `python3 —version` tell you? Also see [this link](https://docs.brew.sh/Homebrew-and-Python).

Answer (score 5):

Please read the info printed by `brew info python`. It also links to the [Homebrew website on Python](https://docs.brew.sh/Homebrew-and-Python), where it says:

> The executables are organized as follows so that Python 2 and Python 3
>   can both be installed without conflict:
>
> - `python3` points to Homebrew’s Python 3.x (if installed)
> - `python2` points to Homebrew’s Python 2.7.x (if installed)
> - `python` points to Homebrew’s Python 2.7.x (if installed) otherwise the macOS system Python. Check out `brew info python` if you wish to
>     add Homebrew’s 3.x python to your PATH.
> - `pip3` points to Homebrew’s Python 3.x’s pip (if installed)
> - `pip` and pip2 point to Homebrew’s Python 2.7.x’s pip (if installed)

Apparently you have installed both Python 2 and 3 through Hombrew. If you wish for `python` to point to Python 3 (instead of 2.7), you have to put `/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin` in your `PATH` *before* other entries.